# Not able to get all the names that are not beginning with 'a'

Tags: python

My own problem

Write a function `Nameskip()` that takes list of names and skips the names beginning with `'a'`

```
def Nameskip(namelst):
    for name in namelst:
        if name[0] in 'a':
            namelst.pop()
        else:
            return names  #Not returning all names
```

Comment: `name[0] == 'a'` or `name.startswith('a')`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `str.startswith` in a list comprehension to filter out the names you want to keep

```
def Nameskip(namelst):
    return [name for name in namelst if not name.startswith('a')]
```

In the version you wrote, you should [avoid mutating a list as you are iterating through it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating).

Comment: That helps, thanks. I will avoid mutating it.